# jquery fadeOut()/fadeIn() hiccup

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code I got from htmled that transitions photos from one to the next to the next. But the 2nd image that appears only appears for an instant and then goes to the next picture. After that the loop is smooth, no problems.

Here's the jquery:

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1500)
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn(1500)
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.zerogravpro.com/yurt/

Comment: (OffT) A user friendly gallery allows the user to pause the show by mouseentering the gallery, to enjoy the image details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving all of your JavaScripts right before the closing `body` tag.

Also, be sure to wrap the additional jQuery in `$(function() {});` so the code doesn't fire until the DOM is ready. See below:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

  setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
  }, 4000); // 4 seconds
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great, but don't forget to close all of the above code off with "})".

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
```

This line does not work because it is called before dom is inited. Hence the second image is shown initially instead of the first, which causes the hiccup.